# How to combine RESTful server with Apache Kafka?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, apache-kafka, long-polling

I've run into an issue due to a lack of knowledge. Could you help me to solve it?

I have 2 servers:

1. A RESTful microservice
2. A microservice interacting with a database

The 1st microservice contains an endpoint (let it be `GET .../{id}` for simplicity) in `Controller` class which return type is `DeferredResult<String>`.

```
@GetMapping(/{id})
public DeferredResult<String> get(@PathVariable("id") final String id) {
    final DeferredResult<String> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
    service.get(id, deferredResult);
    return deferredResult;
}
```

1st and 2nd servers are interacting with each other through Apache Kafka:

1. 1st server gets a `GET` request and invokes a service that produces a message "{id}" in a topic named "getData"
2. 2nd server consumes the "{id}" from the topic with help of `@KafkaListener`
3. 2nd retrieves necessary data and produces it in a topic "returnData" (the data, of course, contains the requested {id})
4. 1st server consumes the message with help of `@KafkaListener`

Everything is done in an asynchronous way.

After 1st server got the data, it needs to respond with it (`.setResult(data)` on `DeferredResult<String>` instance).

This means that I need somehow to match the data, consumed from Kafka, with the correct `DeferredResult<String>` instance.

At this point, seems my approach leads to nowhere.
How can I keep a connection opened and after consuming data from Kafka return it to proper connection?

Comment: Since you are using Spring take a look here for examples on how to use kafka in a synchronous way https://dzone.com/articles/synchronous-kafka-using-spring-request-reply-1

Comment: You could look at the source code for the Kafka REST Proxy if you really want to try something like this

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid this approach. There is no any guarantee that your command will be ever executed but if it will, no guarantee on the response time.

Instead, build a "projection" (e.g., a persistent store/database) from the events you have on your topic and read from it in a normal manner via REST APIs.

The "write" side, however, could react on your POST request by issuing a message on your Kafka topic (that will be *eventually* picked up by the abovementioned projection builder)

Comment: sorry, could you clarify what do you mean by "projection"?

Comment: Having a log of events, that describe your entity changes, by _projection_ we usually mean a purpose-built storage of the entity states (usually the last ones). In short, "read events from Kafka and write the data to the database" (in a way you can easily query it later)

In your original question there's nothing related to the event log, so I probably overthought the question. 

But still, in your case, just go directly to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is async by definition, if you need a response after the request is processed, you shouldn't delay the processing using kafka.
A correct use case for kafka is more like: Your request was received, this is your tracking number, or... in the request provide a callback and make the call to the callback part of the second process.
If you need synchronic response, but worry about backpressure, try using something like ReactiveStreams, Dropwizard using Asyn endpoint works pretty well.
In your solution, you have processes threads (or requests) hanging, waiting for a message that might never come. You have the same results if you process the requests directly, but faster. I guess you use the kafka topics in other flows, wich are synchronous, in that case a callback could be better for you.